# How can I use special characters (i.e., mu symbols) in a GitHub R package?

Tags: r

I have an R Cran package that I have served on GitHub. Some of the scripts have a mu symbol embedded in the code. When I try to load the script using devtools, 
I receive the following error message:

> install_github("user/flamer")
>   Downloading github repo user/flamer@master
>   Installing flamer
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
>     --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
>     "C:/Users/Luke/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOgPoCC/devtools245043733096/thejohncrawford-flamer-af78ede"  \
>     --library="C:/Users/Luke/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" --install-tests

- installing *source* package 'flamer' ...
  ** R
  Error in parse(outFile) : 
  C:/Users/Luke/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOgPoCC/devtools245043733096/thejohncrawford-flamer-af78ede/R/tau_correct.R:27:28: unexpected input
  26: #SpCond
  27: X<-instrument_table$SpCondÎ¼
                             ^
  ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'flamer'

The error occurs on line 27, where there is suppose to a mu symbol rather than "Î¼" It should read "...SpCondμ"

I believe the error occurs as R studio pulls scripts off of git. Has anyone else encountered this problem and know to allow special characters to load from git?

Thanks

Comment: If I wasn't so busy/lazy I would go to meta and request that [mu] get burninated

Comment: You need to edit the package with an editor that can deliver the desired symbol in the encoding expected by R, probably "UTF-8". Windoze apps typically use strange variations for nonASCII characters with their own font mappings.